# Is it possible to use rrule plugin with businessHours in fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, rrule

I've tried using rrule plugin with events in fullcalendar and it works perfectly... So, my question is if it is possible to use it with businessHours as well?

Comment: Nothing in the documentation mentions this possibility. You'd have to try it out, but I doubt it. https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, I've tried it out but as I expected nothing... :/

I was expecting something like that to work just like with events...

`businessHours: [{
      daysOfWeek: [2, 5],
      rrule: {
        freq: "weekly",
        interval: 1,
        byweekday: [4],
        dtstart: "2021-07-22T10:00:00",
        until: '2021-08-20T10:00:00'
      }
    }]`